# What is the correct SE to talk about Web browser addons?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On SuperUser I asked a question about how to use Web browser addons to block stuff on discussion forums, but was told it was off topic. What is the correct SE to talk about this subject?

The ProWebmaster SE says "Usage of web browsers and other software" should go to SuperUser.

Comment: For everyone else's convenience, [here's the question that was asked on Super User](http://superuser.com/q/1118289/380318).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't find your closed superuser question.

The question as you citate here, is probably far too general. But, if you ask from a specific problem in a specific browser addon, there it will be ok.

To find the wanted addons, you can use the http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Thus, what I would suggest:

1. Separate your question in two different parts.
2. Ask for the usable add-on on the softwarerecs.
3. Your question would be probably closed as duplicate (very likely it was asked already a lot of times there), but the dupe will give you probably a lot of browser addons for the task.
4. Download them, try them.
5. Go back with your, this time more specific problems to the SU.

I found the SU and also the softwarerecs quite friendly sites, fulfilling their criterias will be probably easy. They are not the hairsplitting line in the moderation.

---

Now @BenN 's comment showed me your closed SU question. I think it can be done only on a site-specific CSS/JS insertion, which for your specific problem probably doesn't exist. But, with a little CSS/JS experience, you can probably develop your own. So, first you have to on the softwarerecs SE, where you can find such browser addons. Second, you have to implement the CSS/JS insertions for yourself. In your case I would use firefox/firebug/greasemonkey for the task, but in chrome I am not sure.

If you find a problem in the CSS/JS things, you can get help on the stackoverflow.

You can also host your code on the [github](http://github.com).

The SU hasn't to do anything with this whole.

Comment: Oh, wow, I did not know about http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. That will be helpful.